# Writing generic function for tables that works when the input happens to be vector

Tags: r, function, vector, matrix, dataframe

The automatic conversion of 2D `data.frame` or `matrix` to 1D vectors, also good, makes some problems while writing generic functions. For example trying to filter some columns of the input `foo` with a command like `foo[,1:3]` works fine for a `data.frame` or `matrix`:

```
foo=matrix(1:9,nrow=3)
bar = function(x) print(x[,1])
bar(foo) # [1] 1 2 3
```

But consider we first want to filter some rows of `foo`, and it happens that only a single row remains:

```
bar(foo[1,]) # Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This problem may be solved by a simple trick:

```
bar = function(x) {
    if (is.null(dim(x))) x = t(data.frame(x))
    print(x[,1])
}
```

But the problem would be much more complicated if we have other filters on `x` in the body of `bar()` that may convert it again to a vector. Then for every filtering we should check and do the same to ensure what we have is still a table.

The other problems are: missing row names and/or column names if the filtered part of a matrix is only a single row/column. It needs further manipulation to re-organize the filtered part as a matrix, retrieve the original row/column names and assign them to the resulting matrix.

The question is that: How to *simply* convert a function that works for tables a generic one, that if the input happens to be vector it still works?

Comment: I think this is what the `drop` argument is for.

Comment: Instead, consider writing a function that only works with matrices and or data.frames by adding `stopifnot(is.data.frame(x) || is.matrix(x))`. If you were to run `bar(foo[1, ])` it would error out with a meaningful message, and you'd know you have to use `bar(foo[1, , drop = FALSE])` like @joran suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problems when working with data that could be a vector or a data.frame.

Usually, I just create a subset function within the function.

```
foo <- function(dat,rows) { 

if(is.data.frame(dat) || is.matrix(dat)) { 
dat <- dat[rows,] 
} else {
dat <- dat[rows]

... # continue with function
}
```

This method also maintains the class of the original object.

Comment: You may add the joran comment above to complete your answer!