# canonical pattern for handling variable dimension inputs in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I'm writing a function to process numerical input, doing a series of calculation on each column. Id' like the function to seamlessly handle vector, and matrix inputs and return the same class as the input. Im looking to for this to work similar to thew way `diff()` works. is there a canonical pattern for implementing this in R, or do i need to if/else processing on the class of the input?

the best i have come up with so far is:

```
bar <- function(x) {
    m <- as.matrix(x)
    m <- apply(m, 2, function(z) log(diff(z)))
    if (is.null(dim(x))) m <- drop(m)
    return(m)
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you want to calculate `max(diff(x))`, then the result of applying it to a vector is a scalar (i.e., just one number, the max of the diff), and the result of applying it to a matrix is a vector (one number for each column in the matrix). Why would you then want to return a vector in the first case and a matrix in the second? If you just remove the `if` line from your code, don't you get what you need?

Comment: @Oriol, my bad. updated example to properly showcase. the actual calculations i want are quite involved and i don't think they are worth repeating here

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039997/writing-generic-function-for-tables-that-works-when-the-input-happens-to-be-vect?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a canonical pattern, but the `diff` function does check whether the input is a matrix in order to calculate dimensions/length, it then unclasses the input with `r <- unclass(x)`, calculates the differences in `r` with different paths for matrix and vector inputs (using `if`), and it finally reapplies the original class with `class(r) <- oldClass(x)` before returning `r`. As you can see, that is not in essence much difference from what you did, which seems fine to me.

If you want to check the implementation of `diff()`, you can just type this in the console:

```
diff.default
```

Comment: thanks. i didn't realize if could see the diff code like that. i'll just copy their pattern